# My PHP Regex isn't working

Tags: php, regex

I am really new at this I've only seen it before and this is my first attempt. I am trying to get any sentence that starts with "Photo" and ends with a period. I guess Im not getting how to end the regex search with the '.' This is what I got so far:

```
(^[Photo]{5}[a-zA-Z0-9\w\W]*[\.]$)
```

I would like for it to be able to pull the sentences that start with photo out of this string:

```
This is some text. Photo is by you. Some more text. Photo created by me. Some more text. Photo via the internet.
```

EDIT-
What I am doing is writing a php function that will pull out the strings that start with "photo" and end with a period. I want to have that string become a variable so that I can keep it with the picture. The issue is that the writers might not be consistent with it. They will sometimes put "Photo by Some name." or "Photo courtesy of Some Name." or "Photo by Some Name."

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `\bPhoto\b.+?\.`

Comment: The problem is that language sentence are hard to determine where it begins and ends. There is no regex that will help you.

Comment: Im just going to have them start it with the word "Photo" and end it with a '.' and they are going to need to make sure that if they use initials they cannot use periods for the initials.

Answer (score 2):

`^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the whole string, not sentences. I would use `\.?\s+` instead of `^` and `\.` instead of `$`

`[Photo]` matches characters individually, so this is like saying "match 'P' or 'h' or' 'o' ..."
What you want is `(Photo)` or `Photo\s`.

I also added the ungreedy flag `U`

So with those changes this regex should work

```
/(\.?\s+(Photo\s[a-zA-Z0-9\w\W]*\.))/U
```

Comment: Do not need the brackets unless you need it for later

Comment: I'm putting it in this site http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bAI and its not working.

Comment: Oh, what you have in that link is different from whats in your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Ok I edited the question. If thats not the right website I should be using for this, is there a better website for me to mess around with regex?

Comment: In your question it looks like a line of sentences and you want to pull out sentences, but you other example looks like you want to match a line that starts with Photo, the regexes will be different.

Comment: Note that `[\w\W]` matches everything and `[\w\W]*` greedly matches everything.

Comment: I want to pull out the sentence. What I am pulling from is a <figcaption> and it explains the picture and then gives credit for the photo. When pulled from the database it will be in a single string like this: "<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">Guy falls off cliff while ridding his bike and texting. Photo by Innocent Bystander.</figcaption>.

Answer (score 1):

Starts with photo you need

```
 ^photo
```

Ends with period, you need

```
 \.$
```

To fill in the gap you need any characters

```
 .*
```

So the regex is

```
^photo.*\.$
```